# SVG using transform rotation rotates the image every time the image gets updated

Tags: react-native, svg, expo

I'm using expo over react native and have a stateless class that renders a clipped SVG as follows:

```
const svgWidth = 350;
const svgHeight = 260;
const { width } = Layout.window;
const scale = (width / svgWidth) * 0.9;

<Defs>
          <ClipPath id='clip'>
            {/* <Entypo name="controller-play" /> */}
            {/*d='M275, 100 C298.17, 109.5  298.17, 142.313  275, 151.814 L37.8051, 249.071 A28,28,0,0,1,-0.817, 223.164 L-0.817, 28.65 A28,28,0,0,1,37.805, 2.743Z'*/}
            <Path
              d='M113.093,63.183c9.5-23.17,42.313-23.17,51.814,0l97.257,237.195A28,28,0,0,1,236.257,339H41.743a28,28,0,0,1-25.907-38.622Z'
              transform='translate(341.5 -12) rotate(90)'
              scale={scale}
            />
          </ClipPath>
        </Defs>

        <Svg
          width={svgWidth * scale}
          height={svgHeight * scale}
          onPress={onPress}
        >
          <Path
            d='M113.093,63.183c9.5-23.17,42.313-23.17,51.814,0l97.257,237.195A28,28,0,0,1,236.257,339H41.743a28,28,0,0,1-25.907-38.622Z'
            transform='translate(341.5 -12) rotate(90)'
            scale={scale}
            fill='#fffc0007'
            stroke='#fffc0015'
            strokeWidth='10'
          />
        </Svg>
        <Svg
          width={svgWidth * scale}
          height={svgHeight * scale}
          onPress={onPress}
        >
          <Path
            d='M113.093,63.183c9.5-23.17,42.313-23.17,51.814,0l97.257,237.195A28,28,0,0,1,236.257,339H41.743a28,28,0,0,1-25.907-38.622Z'
            transform='translate(341.5 -12) rotate(90)'
            scale={scale}
            fill='none'
            stroke='#70707025'
            strokeWidth='6'
          />
        </Svg>
        <Svg
          width={svgWidth * scale}
          height={svgHeight * scale}
          onPress={onPress}
        >
          <Path
            d='M113.093,63.183c9.5-23.17,42.313-23.17,51.814,0l97.257,237.195A28,28,0,0,1,236.257,339H41.743a28,28,0,0,1-25.907-38.622Z'
            transform='translate(340.5 -12) rotate(90)'
            scale={scale}
            fill='none'
            stroke='#33333317'
            strokeWidth='5'
            strokeLinejoin='round'
          />
        </Svg>
<Image
          href={{
            uri:uri,
            cache: 'force-cache',
          }}
          clipPath='url(#clip)'
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
          preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMax slice'
        />
```

Every time the URL gets updated the shape is rotated as follows:

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENiGq.png)

[After first update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ismt5.png)

[After second update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ystlc.png)

and so on...

Does anybody know how to keep the original layout for each and every render?

Thanks,
Erez

Comment: Do you have more than one element with id="clip" on the page?

Comment: No, it's working fine when initializing the component but when I'm recycling the component with a new image (solves performance issues of large lists) then the shape rotates

Comment: This is an alternative solution: Use this d attribute instead with no transformation: `d="M275, 100
C298.17, 109.5
 298.17, 142.313
 275, 151.814
L37.8051, 249.071
A28,28,0,0,1,-0.817, 223.164
L-0.817, 28.65
A28,28,0,0,1,37.805, 2.743Z"`

Comment: Great! this actually solves my problem... Do you have any converter that you use? because I have another triangle that surrounds this one for border purposes and it doesn't sit right when I change them both so I guess I need to play a bit with the sizes.

10x again @enxaneta

Comment: I don't have a tool. However if you are interested I can explain you the workflow using plain javascript. Alternatively you can give me the d attribute for the other triangle

Comment: it's the same attributes, I've updated it in the original question and you can see the other triangles as the border around the clip itself. when I change every one of their coordinates to the one you suggested the border gets trimmed in some places, Thanks!